# ГербЫ или гЕрбы?

Tags: фонетика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно ставить ударение в слове "гербы"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех падежах единственного и множественного числа ударение в этом слове - на окончании: гербА, гербУ, гербОм, о гербЕ, гербЫ, гербОв, гербАм и т.д